YouTube on macOS not connecting to Roku
macOS Sequoia 15.0.1
Chrome 130.0.6723.58
From the YouTube website on macOS using Chrome, I used to be able to play videos directly on the Roku connected and other stream on my home network.  Roku has the YouTube app installed.  There was a button looking like this:
The casting button no longer seems to exist.
On my iPhone, running YouTube, the casting button still exists, and I am able to see multiple devices include my Roku.
Has this feature been removed from the YouTube website running on macOS.
